# Print a certain output based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that prints the numbers in the given range. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz".For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz". Print a new line after each string or number.

Input Format:- First line will be the number of testcase, T. Next line will have T integers, denoted by N.

Out Format:- For each testcase, print the number from 1 to N. But follow the rules given in the problem statement.

SAMPLE INPUT 1

```
2
3 15
```

This is my code:-

```
n_input = int(input())

x, y = map(int, input().split(" "))

for i in range(1, x + 1):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz", sep="\n")
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz", sep="\n")
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz", sep="\n")
    else:
        print(i, sep="\n")


for i in range(1, y+1):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz", sep="\n")
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz", sep="\n")
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz", sep="\n")
    else:
        print(i, sep="\n")
```

I know my mistake that i have to print according to initial input but i don't know how to fix it.
Thank you

Comment: What is the sample output for it?

Comment: 1
2
Fizz
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz

Comment: You are assuming that T will be 2.

Comment: Which i know is wrong but i don't know how to correct it

Comment: @MohdAlimuddin see my answer below. The key is to store all the test cases in a `list` of size `T`. The number `T` is unnecessary here, in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k = int(input()) # useless given what we're doing below
cases = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for case in cases:
    for k in range(1, case + 1):
        out = ""
        if (k % 3) == 0:
            out += "fizz"
        if (k % 5) == 0:
            out += "buzz"

        if out != "":
            print(out)
        else:
            print(k)
```

The second line is shorthand for

```
cases = []
for i in input().split():
    cases.append(int(i))
```

[Run my Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xSaQo7UW0kGWEHp0oVeJ_iXIcApFsUkh?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

```
Answer in C#: 
A first line is a number of case.
The second line is a value. 
Example : 
   Line1: 3
   Line2: 10,55,20
Example 2:
   Line1: 4
  Line2: 10,55,20, 44
```

Code:

```
using System;
class sasikumarv{
public static void Main()
{
    var read = Console.ReadLine();
    int T= Convert.ToInt32(read);   
    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    var numbers = line.Split(' ');      
   if(first>=1 && first<=10)
    {
    
    for(int cnt=0;cnt<T;cnt++)
    {
     for(int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(numbers[cnt]); i++)                            
     {
        if (i % 15 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz" + " ");
        else if (i % 3 == 0)    
            Console.WriteLine("Fizz" + " ");
        else if (i % 5 == 0)                                            
            Console.WriteLine("Buzz" + " ");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(i + " ");                 
      }
    }
    }
}
}
```